# Object does not work as link

Tags: html, hyperlink, svg

I'm using `object` to display an SVG logo, but unfortunately, the area of the SVG does not function as a link. An `img` tag in the same place would work; I'm not using img because neither firefox nor chrome handle the scaling of the SVG gracefully when included as an `img`.

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DN7xc/

Is there a way to make `object` behave like `img` when included in an `a` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088485/how-to-insert-a-svg-object-into-html-with-links

Comment: @MrSlayer good call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `pointer-events: none;` attribute in the object. That way it will behave as a link from the parent `a` tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).